# onClick: update content of expandable ListView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview

I'm parsing data (Json) from a server to my expandable ListView with the following structure:

```
{
  "package":[ 
    "title":"Selection 1",
    "price": 200,
    "content":[stuff inside the exp listview]
  ]
} ,
{
  "discount":[ 
    "title:"discount 1",
    "amount": 100
  ]
}
```

the result should look like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo45c.jpg)

Parsing the data isn't the problem, I have two problems:

The Discount Buttons should have a button behaviour but only one discount should be pickable (clickable), onClick: the discount gets applied to the ExpandableListView above

I thought about a CardView for the single button which then will be multiplied with the amount of discounts in my json (due an adapter):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="91dp"
android:layout_height="132dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="350dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="Discount" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

But my main problem here is the OnClickBehaviour of the Buttons/CardView which should apply the discount to the price next to the OK Button. After the customer has made his selection, the OK button should access the selection of the discount of my CardView.

This is the ListGroup for the Adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeaderLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_list_header"
        android:textColor="@color/Textwhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mont_bold"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader_Price"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_list_header"
        android:textColor="@color/Textwhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mont_bold"

        />
</RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeaderButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_ripple_dark"
        android:text="@string/btn_ok"
        android:textColor="@color/Textwhite"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mont_bold"
        android:focusable="false"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my adapter class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader,listDataHeaderPrice;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;
    private List<Package> packageList;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Package> packageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList= packageList;
    }


        @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        return packageList.get(groupPosition).getContent().size();

    }

        @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return packageList.get(groupPosition).getContent();
    }

        @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

        @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }


  @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) packageList.get(groupPosition).getTitle();
        /** HEADER TEXT HERE */

        float headerPrice = packageList.get(groupPosition).getPrice();

        if(view==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vip_package_listgroup,null);
        }
        final LinearLayout bgcolor = view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderLayout);
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        TextView lblListHeaderPrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader_Price);
        Button lblListHeaderButton = view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderButton);



        lblListHeaderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (context, drinks_selection.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        lblListHeaderPrice.setText(String.format("%.02f",headerPrice).replace(".",",") +"USD");
        return view;

    }

     @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


        final List<String> childTest = packageList.get(groupPosition).getContent();
        final String childText =  childTest.get(childPosition);

        if(view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vip_package_listitem,null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return view;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use RadioGroup and RadioButtons for selecting discount and add a public method inside the adapter. I assume that Text on RadioButton is the amount for discount, so
code for RadioButtons:

```
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b) {
                mainAdapter.setDiscount(Float.valueOf(compoundButton.getText().toString()));
            }
        }
    };
    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
    rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
    rb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
```

The Adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
//private List<String> listDataHeader, listDataHeaderPrice;
//private HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap;
private List<Package> packageList;
private float discount = 0; //Added

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Package> packageList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.packageList = packageList;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return packageList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return packageList.get(groupPosition).getContent().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return packageList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return packageList.get(groupPosition).getContent().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) packageList.get(groupPosition).getTitle();
    /** HEADER TEXT HERE */

    float headerPrice = packageList.get(groupPosition).getPrice();

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vip_package_listgroup, null);
    }
    LinearLayout bgcolor = view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderLayout);
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    TextView lblListHeaderPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader_Price);
    Button lblListHeaderButton = view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeaderButton);

    lblListHeaderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, drinks_selection.class);
            intent.putExtra("discount", discount); //Added
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    float endPrice = headerPrice + discount; //Added
    if(endPrice < 0) endPrice = 0; //Added
    lblListHeaderPrice.setText(String.format("%.02f", endPrice).replace(".", ",") + "USD"); //Changed
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    List<String> childTest = packageList.get(groupPosition).getContent();
    String childText = childTest.get(childPosition);

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vip_package_listitem, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}

//Added this public method
public void setDiscount(float discount){
    this.discount = discount;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Sir, this should work. The usage of CompoundButton isn't really clear for me, why aren't we using a radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(); instead? Thank you :)!!

Comment: Yes, you can use the radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(). I think that you are parsing your data and will set the text to the RadioButton individually, so I use the CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener which is for individual RadioButton.

Answer (score 0):

> The Discount Buttons should have a button behaviour but only one
>   discount should be pickable

Then you should use a RadioGroup with RadioButtons that you can style.

> OnClickBehaviour of the Buttons/CardView which should apply the
>   discount to the price next to the OK Button

You need to change the dataset when clicking on the discount, I believe it is txtListChild in your case. On `packageList.get(groupPosition).setPrice(price-discount)`

Comment: Yeah but, the "packageList.get(groupPosition).setPrice(price-discount)" is only accessible inside the adapter while my RadioGroup is outside the adapter in the main class. Therefore I cannot access this outside the adapter with a onClickListener (or is it in this case e onSelectedListener?)